# marklogic uncatching SVC-SOCCONN on XQuery

Tags: try-catch, marklogic

When I tray to catch an http-post, It's ok for the **XDMP-URI** but not for the **SVC-SOCCONN**.
The XQuery stops, without any execution of the catch.

This is the extract of the XQuery with the try/catch :

```
let $return := try {
  xdmp:http-post($uri,$options,$doc)
} catch ($e) {
  xdmp:log("HTTP POST KO"),
  <return><code>500</code></return>
}
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce. What version of MarkLogic are you running? Can you try executing the example that I posted and verify that it is uncaught?

Answer (score 0):

The call is lazily evaluated so you’ll only get an error encountered during execution when you actually read the response.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your issue. The following will produce SVC-SOCCONN and is caught by the try/catch, returning `<return><code>500</code></return>` and not the connection error.

```
let $doc := cts:search(doc(), cts:true-query())[1]
let $options := ()
let $uri := "http://10.255.255.1"
let $result := try {
    xdmp:http-post($uri, $options, $doc)
  } catch ($e) {
    xdmp:log("HTTP POST KO"),
    <return><code>500</code></return>
  }
return $result
```

As @hunterhacker pointed out, [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) can sometimes cause some unexpected behaviors. It doesn't appear that is the issue here, unless there is a difference in a particular MarkLogic version (I am testing against the latest currently available, 10.0-8.2). If did want to ensure that an expression was not lazily evaluated, you could use [`xdmp:eager()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:eager).

```
let $result := try {
    xdmp:eager(xdmp:http-post($uri, $options, $doc))
  } catch ($e) {
    xdmp:log("HTTP POST KO"),
    <return><code>500</code></return>
  }
return $result
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, but the error was in the catch clause, because I call an other function than xdmp:log, and this function create the uncatching. In this case the intial error was thrown. I didn't know the xdmp:eager() function. Thank you for answer!