# http-post - SVC-UTF8SEQ - Invalid UTF-8 escape sequence: 0xf4 0x74

Tags: marklogic

I use the ML version **10.0-7.3**
I have a problem with the **http-post** return when the host is unknown.
I try to catch the error, but it's impossible.
Here is the very reduced code :

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $return := try {xdmp:http-post("http://toto/titi")} catch ($e) { $e}
return $return
```

and the result in the console is :

```
*[1.0-ml] SVC-UTF8SEQ: let $return := try { xdmp:http-post("http://toto/titi") } catch ($e) { $e } return $return -- Invalid UTF-8 escape sequence: 0xf4 0x74
Stack Trace
At line 4 column 0:
In xdmp:eval("xquery version &quot;1.0-ml&quot;;&#10;&#10;&#10;let $return := ...", (), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>17567623539722960267</database>...</options>)
2.
3.
4. l et $return := try {
5. xdmp:http-post("http://toto/titi")}
6. catch ($e)*
```

Comment: This seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/70494087/14419 where you indicated the issue was in your catch clause.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the `xdmp:http-post()` is being [lazily evaluated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), only resolved when the `$return` variable is dereferenced.

- https://www.marklogic.com/blog/lazy-evaluation/
- https://www.marklogic.com/blog/lazy-vs-eager-evaluation/

Try using [`xdmp:eager()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:eager)

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $return := try { xdmp:eager(xdmp:http-post("http://toto/titi")) } catch ($e) { $e}
return $return
```

Or move everything inside of the `try{}`

Comment: I don't understand the problem of lazy or eager evaluation in this case, this is only one evaluation with the return. The problem is when the http-post is executed.
If i undo the try i have exactly the same error

Answer (score 0):

I try on the version : 10.0-8.2 on centos and the catch is OK with the response :

```
<response xmlns="xdmp:http">
<code>404
</code>
<message>Not Found
</message>
<headers>
<server>nginx/1.14.1
</server>
<date>Mon, 17 Jan 2022 13:07:47 GMT
</date>
<content-type>text/html
</content-type>
<content-length>3971
</content-length>
<connection>keep-alive
</connection>
<etag>"5d9bab28-f83"
</etag>
</headers>
</response>
```

Comment: I have the same error on Windows 10.0-8.3
I think that it's a bug on the Windows implementation with the non utf-8 encoding on windows OS